# Can't scroll through a div | Selenium | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

A few questions were posted a while back about scrolling through a list of IG followers, this doesn't seem to work for a the list of IG likes on a post, as the structure seems to be a div with a list of divs inside of it.

I've tried clicking on the window (to make it scrollable) and using downward arrow (the clicking enabled scrolling when I did it manually but didn't work on the bot), using the method that was posted on the "scrolling through a list of IG followers" question:

```
element= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

this method as well:

```
recentList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='...']")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500);")
```

Again, I want to scroll through the list and have it load more profiles. Here's what the HTML looks like btw

[image: pic]

Comment: Have you tried this:
`body = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body')`
`body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)`

Comment: no didn't work, gives an 'element not interactable' error. Just so we're clear I want to scroll down the list of likes and not the entire page. So does this work on divs, cause it might be me doing it wrong